# What is the issue on my recursive function made in go?

Tags: function, go, recursion, multiple-return-values

I am learning Golang with the book "[The Go Programming Language](https://www.gopl.io/)", in chapter 5 section 5.3 (Multiple Return Values) exercise 5.5 I have to implement the function `countWordAndImages` that receives an html Node from the ([golang.org/x/net](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net)) package, and counts the number of words and images inside an html file, I implemented the following function, but for any reason I receive **0 values** for each `words` and `images` returned variables.

```golang
func countWordsAndImages(n *html.Node) (words, images int) {
    if n.Type == html.TextNode {
        words += wordCount(n.Data)
    } else if n.Type == html.ElementNode && n.Data == "img" { // if tag is img on element node
        images++
    }
    for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = n.NextSibling {
        tmp_words, tmp_images := countWordsAndImages(c)
        words, images = words+tmp_words, images+tmp_images
    }
    return words, images
}

func wordCount(s string) int {
    n := 0
    scan := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(s))
    scan.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
    for scan.Scan() {
        n++
    }
    return n
}
```

I tried to avoid naming the return varibles tuple in the function (`(int, int)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `c.NextSibling` to advance to the next sibling, not `n.NextSibling`:

```
for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
    ⋮
```

https://go.dev/play/p/cm51yG8Y7Ry